# Sorting test cases of a test suite in order of execution in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, test-suite, regression-testing

I have a test suite in Visual Studio 2015 in C#. I want the tests to be sorted in order of their execution. Is there a way to do it ?

Currently they are sorted in alphabetical order after execution.

Comment: Why do you care how the methods in your test-fixtures are sorted? Usually the order of tests is undeterministic and should not have any affect, however there may be scenarios where the order might tackle a role.

Comment: @HimBromBeere While doing regression some test methods affect the others ( make them fail ). I want to find out the the cause. I also want to avoid tedious  task of debugging the whole test suite.